# mail smtpport configuration in Google cloud - zimbramailcow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have installed zimbra on GCP VM. Im able to received mail from outer and inner network but unable to send mail in outer network. I have  change smtp port to 2525 and define firewall but still not able to send mail.

br//
madhur

Comment: Are you able to provide more details? Some settings you've tried or errors you're receiving?

Comment: only "Delayed Mail (still being retried)" and delivery failed"

Comment: i have tried zimbra and mailcow both and have same issue

Answer (score 0):

**For security reasons Google blocks SMTP traffic and that is why you can't send email:**

> By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports
> but port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All other
> ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.

See also the documentation [what kind of traffic gets always blocked by default in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) (and you can't change it).

**The only way to semd emails from you GCP instances is to use trusted 3rd party tools such as: SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet.**

Have a look at the documentation on [how to send emails from GCP VM's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail), which provider is best suited for you and how to configure specific service.